# Bootstrap - Do I have to add that class to every element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In CSS I'm used to define styles globally for all elements like `button { /* style stuff */ }`

Is there a way to set all buttons to bootstraps `btn btn-sm btn-default` without explicitly setting the class for every element?

For example something like

```
button {
  btn btn-sm btn-default
}
```

Comment: You will have to modify the btn class in the bootstrap.css file. See bitten's answer

Comment: You can create a new class, where you combine styles from all classes that you need and use that single class where you need.

Answer (score 4):

If you are familiar with LESS, you could edit the bootstrap core and prepend each `.btn` with `button`, so `.btn, button`, and recompile the less. [buttons.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/buttons.less) is the file you want to be looking at.

Alternatively, just do a search and replace for "`.btn {`" and replace it with "`.btn, button {`" in the compiled css of bootstrap. Although you will have to do this multiple times and be quite careful, since there are a lot of subclasses in bootstrap (`.btn-default`, `.btn-primary` and so on).

Answer (score 1):

In other ways, you can add class to all buttons using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('button').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-default');
})
```

Comment: watch out for a flash of unstyled content (FOUC/FOUT) though

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using LESS or any other CSS extension I would say you could just make a separate stylesheet (let's call it custom.css - most of us use a custom stylesheet in addition to frameworks stylesheets anyway) and add the style there. For example:

```
button {
  // Here what ever is inside bootstraps btn-sm and btn-default and even set the styles with !important so they will over write the bootstrap defaults for sure
}
```

Then set it as the last stylesheet in your document, for example like this:

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And this way all your buttons should have the desired style and you could still use other features of bootstrap CSS.

Comment: i would disagree in using `!important` in this case. as long as your `custom.css` comes after `bootstrap.css`, custom will happily overwrite bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah I know `!important` is not good practice. I'm just not sure if bootsrap has any importants in it's own core CSS etc. I'm glad if they don't and then you don't need to use `!important` of course.